# Why is Pokemon Go running on unsupported devices?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, pokemon-go

If most of the devices are not supported ARCore, then why is Pokemon Go  running on every device?
My device is not supported by ARCore but Pokemon Go is on it with full performance.

Why?

Comment: Pokémon GO uses ARKit on compatible iOS devices (and calls the resulting gameplay "AR+"). Without ARKit, PoGO uses its own, less sophisticated AR technology. With AR+, a Pokémon stays anchored to a real-world position once it appears, and you can walk around behind it (this is called tracking with 6 degrees of freedom, or 6DoF). Without, the Pokémon always appears a fixed distance away from the camera and you can't walk around to see its backside (3 degrees of freedom, or 3DoF). Implementing 3DoF tracking is relatively easy using the motion sensors built into nearly every device.

Comment: so building AR apps doesn't require ARcore or ARkit, jus use camera overay feature and unity3d for modals ??

Comment: Yes, you can build 3DoF "sorta AR" with just a camera overlay and the 3D (game) engine of your choice plus some basic use of motion tracking, but you don't get a very convincing AR illusion. What ARKit (or ARCore) gives you is tools to create much more realistic AR, without investing man-years of R&D in your own computer vision and motion analysis pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> Until October 2017, Pokemon Go appears to use a Niantic made `AR engine`. At a high level, the game placed the Pokemon globally in space at a server defined location (the `spawn point`). The AR engine used the phone’s GPS and compass to determine if the phone should be moved to the left or to the right. Eventually, the phone pointed to the right heading and the AR engine drawed the 3D model over the video coming from the camera. At that time there was no attempt to perform mapping of the environment, surface recognition, etc. That was a simple, yet very effective technique which created the stunning effects we’ve all seen.
>
> After that Niantic has shown prototypes of Pokemon GO using ARKit for iOS. It is easy to notice enhancements: missed pokeballs appear to bounce very naturally on the sidewalk and respect physics, it feels like Pikachu naturally walks on the sidewalk as opposed to floating in the air with the currently released game. Most observers expected Niantic to replace the current engine with ARKit (iOS) and ARCore (Android), possibly via Unity 3D AR APIs.

In early 2018 Niantic improved the aspect of the game on Android by adding support for ARCore, Google’s augmented reality SDK. And a similar update to what we’ve already seen on iOS 11, which was updated to support ARKit. The iOS update gave the virtual monsters a much greater sense of presence in the world, due to camera tracking, allowing them to more accurately stand on real-world surfaces rather than floating in the center of the frame. Android users will need a phone compatible with ARCore in order to use the new “AR+” mode.

Prior to AR+, Pokémon Go would use rough approximations of where objects were to try and place the Pokémon in your environment, but it was mostly a clunky workaround that functioned mostly as a novelty feature. The new AR+ mode also lets iOS users take advantage of a new capture bonus, called `expert handler`, that involves sneaking up close to a Pokémon, so as not to scare it away, in order to more easily capture it. With ARKit, since it’s designed to use the camera with the gyroscope and all the sensors, it actually feeds in 60 fps with full resolution. It’s a lot more performant and it actually uses less battery than the original AR mode.

For iOS users there's a standard list of supported devices:

- iPhone 6s and higher
- iPad 2017 and higher

For Android users not everything is clear. Let's see why. Even if you have an officially unsupported device with poor-calibrated sensors you can still use ARCore on your phone. For example, [ARCore for All](https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all) allows you do it. So for Niantic, as well, there's no difficulties to make every Android phone suitable for Pokemon Go.

Hope this helps.